# Understanding the verb & noun relation (Define>Definition vs Combine>Combination)

Tags: verbs, nouns

As an English language, I need help to understand the relation of noun with verb. In other words, derivation of noun from verb.

I found that the noun of Combine is Combin**a**tion but for Define, it is Defin**i**tion. So, Why they are differently deals with verb?

I.e Why is it not Combin**i**tion or Defin**a**tion?

I just asked this question in order to understand the derivation of noun from verb. For instance, as given in above example, what principle/rule it follows? Why they don't follow same principle/rule?

<sub>Note: I'm talking about the noun which ends with "tion" and verb with "ine".</sub>

Comment: We borrowed all of those words from French: definir->definition combiner->combinaison. Maybe it has something to do with whether the french infinitive ends with -ir or -er.

Comment: If you ask the French, they will refer you back to the Romans: definio, combino.

Comment: Another example: 'define' and 'refine' look similar, but 'definition' and 'refinement' are totally different. You can find many more of them.

Comment: @Glorfindel, words ending in -ment are also of french origin, but they do not have a latin root. The oldest that I can find is pay->payment, which is 13th Century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is etymology.

Many English words are built from a *[stem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem)* and some [prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix) and [suffixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix). (I think this is true of most languages.) There are many suffixes that preserve the core idea of the word, and give it a particular grammatical nature and a particular meaning. For example, from the stem *defin-*, you can build the verb *define* (to give something a definition), the noun *definition* (the act of giving something a definition, or the outcome of this act), the (uncommon) noun *definer* (someone or something that defines), etc.

Many of these stems, prefixes and suffixes existed in ancestor languages of English. Many of the resulting words existed in ancestor languages, and sometimes different words in the same family evolved differently.

The examples you give are quite illustrative. The verb *define* comes from the Latin verb *[definire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definio#Latin)*, and the noun *definition* comes from the Latin noun *[definitio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definitio#Latin)*. The verb *combine* comes from the Latin verb *[combinare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/combino#Latin)*, and the noun *combination* comes from the Latin noun *[combinatio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/combinatio)*. Note how one pair has the infinitive verb ending in *-are* and the noun ending in *-atio*, and the other pair has the infinitive ending in *-ire* and the noun ending in *-itio*. What happened here is that the ending of the verb was eroded: Latin verbs had over a hundred different endings depending on the mood, tense and person, whereas English has 5. Many verb endings got simplified to *-e* (often in French before they reached English), which erased the previous vowel. So what happened isn't that *defin-* got the suffix *-ition* and *combin-* got the suffix *-ation*, but rather that *defini-* and *combina-* both lost their ending vowel.

Although many stems of this type end with the vowel *-a* or *-i*, Latin also had the vowel *e*, as in. *[delere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deleo#Latin)*, which gave the English words *delete* and *deletion* through a less direct route). Some stems had no final vowel, e.g. *[cedere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cedo#Latin)* (many forms of the verb, including the infinitive, have an additional *-e-* to ease pronunciation), giving *cede* in English, and the associated noun *[cessio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cessio#Latin)* (whence *cession*) where the suffix and the final consonant had merged together and diverged already in an ancestor language of Latin.

The suffix *[-tion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tion)* to form a noun from a verb, meaning the action itself or the outcome of this action, was very common in Latin (shown in the form *-tio* above, but the *-n* was already present in some cases) and in French (also spelled *-tion*) but it is no longer [productive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/productive#Adjective) in English.

English has many other [suffixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_suffixes), some of them productive, most of them not. Most of these suffixes come from Latin, often through French, even though English is primarily a Germanic language. The reason for this is historical: German was the language of ordinary people (who mostly use existing words to designates objects from everyday life), French and Latin were the languages of learned people (who invent new concepts and make up words for them).